# HTML Toggle menu is not working in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

My site toggle menu works properly on a desktop but is not working in mobile devices. When I click on Toggle Menu in my smartphone nothing happens (no action).

The following HTML code is used for the toggle menu.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("bmenu_toggle");
  if (x.className === "hidden") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('reset.css');
body {
  font-family: "Times", serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
legend {
  font-family: var(--title-font);
}

legend {
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 2px 1rem 3px;
}

fieldset,
fieldset legend {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

legend {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 var(--shadow);
}

fieldset {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0 var(--shadow);
}

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

main.app {
  display: table;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 667px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

BMENU.CSS
/** appearance **/

 :root {
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.bmenu {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav.bmenu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1.25rem 0 1.25rem 1.25rem;
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav.bmenu a:link,
nav.bmenu a:visited {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.bmenu>* {
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav.bmenu>a,
nav.bmenu>hr {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.bmenu header {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

nav.bmenu article.panel::before {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2000;
  height: calc(100% - 2*(0.5*1rem));
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0.5*1rem);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav.bmenu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
}

nav.bmenu>hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-top-style: solid;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

nav.bmenu article.panel {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(463px - 2*1.25rem);
}

nav.bmenu article.panel section.titled-group {
  min-width: 160px;
}

nav.bmenu section.titled-group:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

nav.bmenu div.column {
  min-width: 210px;
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

label.bmenu.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/** behaviour **/

.bmenu a,
label.bmenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

article.panel {
  display: none;
}

div.hide-at-start-wrapper {
  min-width: 720px;
}

#bmenu_toggle~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu>article.panel:nth-of-type(10) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#bmenu_toggle~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu>article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(10),
#bmenu_toggle~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu>a:focus:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(10),
#bmenu_toggle~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(10) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(1):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(1),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(1):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(1):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(10),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(1):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(10) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(2):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(2),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(2):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(3):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(3),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(3):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(4):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(4),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(4):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(5):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(5),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(5):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(6):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(6),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(6):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(6) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(7):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(7),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(7):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(7) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(8):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(8),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(8):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(8) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(9):focus~article.panel:nth-of-type(9),
nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(9):hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(9) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(1)~article.panel:nth-of-type(1),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(1)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(2)~article.panel:nth-of-type(2),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(2)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(3)~article.panel:nth-of-type(3),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(3)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(4)~article.panel:nth-of-type(4),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(4)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(5)~article.panel:nth-of-type(5),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(5)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(6)~article.panel:nth-of-type(6),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(6)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(6) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(7)~article.panel:nth-of-type(7),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(7)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(7) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(8)~article.panel:nth-of-type(8),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(8)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(8) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover:not(.no-panel)~a:focus:nth-of-type(9)~article.panel:nth-of-type(9),
nav.bmenu>a:focus:nth-of-type(9)~a:hover:not(.no-panel)~article.panel:nth-of-type(9) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(1):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(2):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(3):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(4):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(5):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(6):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(6) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(7):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(7) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(8):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(8) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>a:nth-of-type(9):focus~article.panel:hover~article.panel:nth-of-type(9) {
  display: none;
}

nav.bmenu>article.panel:hover {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav.bmenu>article.panel:hover~article.panel {
  display: none;
}

#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu>a::after {
  border-color: black;
}

#bmenu_toggle:checked~label.bmenu.toggle:hover .heavy {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}

#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~label.bmenu.toggle:hover .heavy {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 silver;
}

#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~label.bmenu.toggle:hover {
  color: silver;
}

#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~label.bmenu.toggle {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover,
nav.bmenu>a:focus {}

nav.bmenu>a:not(.no-panel):hover::before,
nav.bmenu>a:not(.no-panel):focus::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  left: -1.25rem;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.3em;
  background-color: white;
}

nav.bmenu>a:not(.no-panel)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  /* centered vertically and pointing right */
  /* just maths, bitches, MATHS */
  right: calc(0.5*0.5em + 1.25em);
  top: calc(50% + 0.5*0.5*0.5em);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
}

nav.bmenu>a:hover::after,
nav.bmenu>a:focus::after {
  border-color: white;
}

nav.bmenu>article.panel a:hover,
nav.bmenu>a.no-panel:hover {
  color: black;
  background: yellow;
}

label {
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

label.bmenu.toggle {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.heavy {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.2);
  transform: scaleX(1.2);
  margin-right: 1px;
}


/** animation **/

input#bmenu_toggle:checked~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
  animation: roll-open 0.4s ease 0s normal forwards;
  transition: padding 0.1s ease, color 0.2s ease 0.1s;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

input#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
  animation: roll-closed 0.4s ease 0s normal forwards;
  transition: padding 0.1s ease 0.2s, color 0.2s ease;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
}

@keyframes roll-open {
  0% {
    max-height: 0;
  }
  99% {
    max-height: 463px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: unset;
  }
}

@keyframes roll-closed {
  0% {
    max-height: unset;
  }
  1% {
    max-height: 463px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hide-at-start {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

nav.bmenu.animated>a::after {
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

div.hide-at-start-wrapper {
  animation: hide-at-start 0.5s ease 0s normal forwards;
}


/** triangular hover regions **/

nav.bmenu.panel>a {
  position: relative;
}

nav.bmenu.panel>a>span.triangle-origin {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav.bmenu.panel>a>span.triangle-origin:hover::after {
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1001;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  right: -300px;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  /**
        outline: 1px solid lime;
        **/
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg) translate(0, -100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg) translate(0, -100%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg) translate(0, -100%);
}

nav.bmenu.panel>article.panel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1002;
}


/** fix start issue **/

nav.bmenu article.panel:nth-of-type(1),
nav.bmenu article.panel:nth-of-type(10) {
  min-width: 460px;
}


/** specific cross browser **/

@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  nav.bmenu.panel {
    display: table;
  }
  input#bmenu_toggle:checked~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
    animation: 0;
    transition: 0;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
  }
  input#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
    animation: 0;
    transition: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.bmenu.animated>a::after {
    transition: 0;
  }
  div.hide-at-start-wrapper {
    animation: 0;
  }
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none),
(-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  nav.bmenu.panel {
    display: table;
  }
  input#bmenu_toggle:checked~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
    animation: 0;
    transition: 0;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
  }
  input#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
    animation: 0;
    transition: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.bmenu.animated>a::after {
    transition: 0;
  }
  div.hide-at-start-wrapper {
    animation: 0;
  }
}

@media screen\0 {
  nav.bmenu.panel {
    display: table;
  }
  input#bmenu_toggle:checked~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
    animation: 0;
    transition: 0;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
  }
  input#bmenu_toggle:not(:checked)~div.hide-at-start-wrapper>nav.bmenu.panel {
    animation: 0;
    transition: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.bmenu.animated>a::after {
    transition: 0;
  }
  div.hide-at-start-wrapper {
    animation: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Test Menu</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href=menucss/style.css>
<link rel=stylesheet href=menucss/bmenu.css>
<input id=bmenu_toggle type=checkbox name=bmenu-open class=hidden>
<label class="bmenu toggle" for=bmenu_toggle accesskey=1>
    <header><span class=heavy>&#x2630;</span> Menu</header>
    </label>
<div class=hide-at-start-wrapper>
  <nav class="bmenu panel animated">
    <a href=#><span class=triangle-origin>Home</span></a><a href=#><span class=triangle-origin>On-line</span></a>
    <a href=#><span class=triangle-origin>Documents</span></a>
    <article class=panel>
      <div class=column>
        <section class=titled-group>
          <header>Categories</header>
          <a href=#>Apps</a>
          <a href=#>Software</a>
          <a href=#>Books</a>


        </section>
      </div>



  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: so are you using js or css , i see css ref in the code .

Comment: Any JavaScript code in relation to `#bmenu_toggle` ?

Comment: Does the css toggle the menu layer with hover? If so, try to push the Toggle Menu for several seconds (this means, you hover the button).

Comment: Can you show the full html, the css and the js code?

Comment: I'm showing the full html and the css code. I have no js code. :/- No javascript code.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem but one thing you can get rid of is `div.hide-at-start-wrapper{ min-width: 720px; }`. You don't want that, especially on mobile.

Comment: Is there any error in the console log on? If you find any error on desktop, it may cause the problem on phone.
With your code, it works for me.

Comment: So, I put this inside Wordpress HTML CODE. It doesn't work on mobile devices.

Comment: @AmmoPT, so, it still doesn't work!

Comment: @DiabloSteve i didn't find any error